# Android Realm .query extensions

Tags: android, kotlin, realm

I would like to use the realm kotlin query functionality that is demonstrated on the mongodb website.

E.g.

`Filter results to retrieve a specific segment of objects with realm.query()`

Which links to:

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm-sdks/kotlin/latest/library-base/-realm%20-kotlin%20-s-d-k/io.realm.kotlin.query/-realm-query/query.html

And shows the following example:

```
// Find frogs where name is 'Michigan J. Frog'
val michiganFrogs: RealmResults<Frog> =
    realm.query<Frog>("name = 'Michigan J. Frog'").find()

// Find frogs where age > 3 AND species is 'Green'
val oldGreenFrogs: RealmResults<Frog> =
    realm.query<Frog>("age > 3 AND species = 'green'").find()
```

I'm assuming the `realm` in the examples is equivalent to `Realm.getDefaultInstance()`
However I am unable to resolve the reference

```
Unresolved reference: query
```

Here are the plugins and dependencies used:

Project level: `classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:10.11.1"`

Module level:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'realm-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}
```

I figured I must need to add another dependency or plugin to provide the .query extension or functionality? It doesn't appear to be explained anywhere